# 227 Entering Passive Mode (0,0,0,0,...) when connecting to vsftpd FTP server

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, ftp, port-forwarding, vsftpd

As said in the title, I don't manage to connect my Windows 10 host to my FTP server on the VirtualBox guest side (Ubuntu 18.04).
On the guest side, the vsftpd server works fine, I can connect without any problem.

So I tried to forward the associated port to the host (NAT) and tried to connect to the server via FileZilla. It does login, but always fails to retrieve directory listing. I tried deactivating the firewalls, giving all the access permissions to the folder but it doesn't change anything.

I read that it could be a problem of passive mode there:
[Problems with FTP file access to VirtualBox guest running Windows 2008 Server R2 x64](https://superuser.com/questions/1094347/problems-with-ftp-file-access-to-virtualbox-guest-running-windows-2008-server-r2)

So I added the following lines to [my `vsftpd.conf`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENaYW.png):

```
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_min_port=8020
pasv_max_port=8020
port_enable=YES
pasv_address=127.0.0.1
```

I forwarded the port 8020 but I now get the following error on FileZilla:

> The data connection could not be established: WSAEADDRNOTAVAIL - Cannot assign requested address

Full FileZilla response:

```
Status: Connecting to 127.0.0.1:2100...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Server does not support non-ASCII characters.
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/home/cakephp" is the current directory
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Switching to Binary mode.
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (0,0,0,0,31,84).
Command:    LIST
Error:  The data connection could not be established:
WSAEADDRNOTAVAIL - Cannot assign requested address
Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
Status: Disconnected from server
```

I'm a bit lost with this, does anybody have a suggestion?
Thanks in advance

---

**EDIT1:**
Without any kind of hope, I also tried to access from the Windows Command Prompt. It does connect but when I `ls` the current folder I get the following error:

```
500 illegal PORT command.
425 use PORT or PASV first.
```

But I guess that this is because [ftp.exe doesn't support passive mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18643542/12366189).

Just in case it can help, you can find here [my whole current vsftpd config file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/91zq33f1r88cwl3/vsftpd.txt?dl=0).
Also, I can seamlessly access to the guest SSH server from the host with Putty.

**EDIT2:**
I set `listen_ipv6` to `YES`, changed `pasv_max_port` to 8030 to increase the number of passive ports and forwarded them. I get the following logs from FileZilla:

```
Status:  Connecting to 127.0.0.1:2100...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Server does not support non-ASCII characters.
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/home/cakephp" is the current directory
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Switching to Binary mode.
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (0,0,0,0,31,90).
Command:    LIST
Error:  The data connection could not be established: WSAEADDRNOTAVAIL - Cannot assign requested address
Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (0,0,0,0,31,84).

The `0,0,0,0` is most probably due to a known bug in vsftpd.

If that's the case, to fix this, make sure the server does not listen on IPv6 address:

```
listen_ipv6=NO
listen=YES
```

For details, see a similar question on Server Fault:
[Vsftpd passive reply with 0,0,0,0 address even with correct pasv_address](https://serverfault.com/q/821025/168875)