# How to port forward passive FTP from a router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, ftp

I have a TP-Link archer c7 that I use as an access point connected to my ZTE mf283 router. To my TP-Link ac I have connected a 250GB external HDD which I use as storage for my FTP server that I set up on my TP-Link router.

That works great on my local network but I wanna be able to connect to my router from outside my network so I tried portforwarding but I soon found that that I need to use passive FTP. Now I understand theory more or less but how can I set that up so that it works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to:

- Forward the FTP control connection port 21.
- Forward the passive mode data connection port range (server-specific, usually configurable).
- Configure your FTP server with the external IP address of the router, so that the server reports the correct address to the clients.

Some references:

- My article on [network configuration for FTP modes](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ftp_modes);
- My answer to [Connection to FileZilla FTP server works, but directory listing fails](https://superuser.com/q/729876/213663).